# Why is past continuous used instead of simple present in this general statement?

Tags: present-simple, past-continuous

> This is exactly the kind of question ELL **is hoping** to avoid. We don’t want to become a proofreading service, where we are bombarded with sentences or paragraphs from resumés, school essays, technical papers, and love letters, all asking: Is this grammatically correct?

Why past continuous as this is a general statement, would present simple fit too in this case is why put a duration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The present continuous  (it is not past continuous) reinforces the idea that this is an ongoing hope.

P.S. The speaker can frame the statement as a "general statement"  (it is our practice to discourage such questions--we don't want them) or as specific statement (we have a consistent and persistent desire to discourage such questions in the likelihood of there being an unending stream of such questions if we don't discourage them. That possibility has been *on our minds*. ).  **The sentence itself does not "belong" exclusively in the one or the other category by virtue of some intrinsic quality.**  Such choices of tense  *express* what the speaker has in mind.

Answer (score 1):

First of all "is hoping" is present progressive. It's being used here in order to express that the hope is a continuous sentiment.